# Plugin already loaded

Tags: go, plugins

I'm facing this strange issue when I'm loading a plugin for the second time it's throwing error

`plugin.Open("/path/to/plugin"): plugin already loaded`

From the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin), it says that

```
 Open opens a Go plugin. If a path has already been opened, then the existing *Plugin is returned. 
 It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.
```

However this is not the case when I try to load the plugin more that once.
[Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19004) mentions this, but the fix suggested isn't working with newer version.

A minimum reproducible example can be found [here](https://github.com/jeffy-mathew/go-plugin-issue)

Any helps are appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is issue [#47298](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47298). You can't load the exact same plugin using two different .so names.

I can think of these possible workarounds:

1. Use a unique module path (`go.mod`) for different plugins, and build the entire subfolder instead of `plugin.go`.

   `plugin1/go.mod`:

   ```
   module plugin1
   . . .
   ```

   `$ go build -buildmode=plugin -o ../driver/plugin1.so`

   `plugin2/go.mod`:

   ```
   module plugin2
   . . .
   ```

   `$ go build -buildmode=plugin -o ../driver/plugin2.so`
2. When building from a source file (like `plugin.go`), the plugin path is generated from the SHA hash of the source code. So you can change at least 1 character in the source code, and you'll get a different plugin path.

   (modify `plugin.go`)

   `$ go build -buildmode=plugin -o ../driver/plugin1.so plugin.go`

   `$ readelf -aW ../driver/plugin1.so | grep PluginFunc`

   - will print a different name like `plugin/unnamed-27fe628be05583084aa4668ab292c47e13b9e93d.PluginFunc`